# How to add google-services.json in Android?

Tags: android, google-play-services

The error is:

> File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The
>   Google Quickstart Plugin cannot function without it.

Comment: I have added this is in app folder although this error comes

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Above asked question has been solved as according to documentation at developer.google.com https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config

> 2018 Edit : [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) Deprecated, use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

The file `google-services.json` should be pasted in the app/ directory.
After this is when I sync the project with gradle file the unexpected Top level exception error comes. This is occurring because:

Project-Level Gradle File having

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
}
```

and App-Level Gradle File having:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0' // commenting this lineworks for me
}
```

The top line is creating a conflict between this and `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'` So I make comment it now it works Fine and no error of
File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Quickstart Plugin cannot function without it.

Comment: i accidentally kept it in root folder , however keeping it in root_folder/app resolved issue

Comment: <https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config> results in a 404 "Page Not Found" error page.

Answer (score 24):

The [document says](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#troubleshooting):

> Copy the file into the `app/` folder of your Android Studio project, or
>   into the `app/src/{build_type}` folder if you are using multiple build
>   types.

Answer (score 23):

It should be on `Project -> app` folder

**Please find the screenshot from Firebase website**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Instead of putting in root folder as given in docs of firebase, just copy the google-json file in the projectname/app 's root folder and it works fine then .
Its just simple !

Answer (score 3):

**WINDOWS**

1. Open Terminal window in Android Studio `(Alt+F12 or View->Tool Windows->Terminal).`
   Then type

> "move file_path/google-services.json app/"

without double quotes.

eg

```
move C:\Users\siva\Downloads\google-services.json app/
```

**LINUX**

1. Open Android Studio Terminal and type this

> scp file_path/google-services.json app/

eg:

```
scp '/home/developer/Desktop/google-services.json' 'app/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Click right above the app i.e **android(drop down list)** in android studio.Select the **Project** from drop down and paste the json file by right click over the **app package** and then sync it....

Comment: paste from where?

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates your `package_name` in your `google-services.json` might be wrong. I personally had this issue when I used

```
buildTypes {
    ...

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
    }
}
```

in my `build.gradle`. So, when I wanted to debug, the name of the application was ("all of a sudden") `app.something.debug` instead of `app.something`. I was able to run the debug when I changed the said `package_name`...

Comment: And the solution is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320303/2910520

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the "google-service.json" file from Firebase
2. Go to this address in windows explorer "C:\Users\Your-Username\AndroidStudioProjects" You will see a list of your Android Studio projects
3. Open a desired project, navigate to "app" folder and paste the .json file
4. Go to Android Studio and click on "Sync with file system", located in dropdown menu (File>Sync with file system)
5. Now sync with Gradle and everything should be fine

Answer (score 0):

google-services.json file work like API keys means it store your project_id and api key with json format for all google services(Which enable by you at google console) so no need manage all at different places.

## Important process when uses google-services.json

at application gradle you should add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'.
```

at top level gradle you should add below dependency

```
  dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: You can download from google console and put at app location

Comment: ViramP Im sorry, we are here using automatic assistant in the new AS. I've found a cause, assistant stopped occasionally, need to just re-run it.