# How to create an Android Studio project from a subdirectory in a github repo

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to create an android studio project from [this directory](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging) on github. I tried `VCS` -> `Checkout from Version Control` in `Android Studio`, but there is no url for this directory in the repo, so I'm not sure hot to clone just this subdirectory.

I also tried downloading the whole repo, doing `File` -> `New` -> `Import Project` in `Android Studio`, and selecting the messaging subdirectory as the folder to import. This showed a build progress bar, but after it finished, there was no imported project.

How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding here but how is it different from cloning the whole repo and just opening the subdirectory you want from Android Studio?

Comment: because i cloned the whole repo and i can't run anything. it just shows one big project file containing a bunch of different android projects, and i can't isolate a single one. i can view the files, but i can't run any of the projects

Comment: @thebeest : I know i am late, but how did you manage to solve it ? Were you able to clone this sub directory with VCS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it now. Go back to [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android). Then hit `Download Zip` and unzip it. In `Android Studio` go to `File -> Open ->` then to the `quickstart-android-master` and then down to `messaging`. Do NOT open `quickstart-android-master` go down to `messaging` and open that.

**EDIT**

Be aware you will have to follow these instructions to get the project to build and run.

[Add google-services.json in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072568/add-google-services-json-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if its the correct way, but i resolved it with the following steps on Android Studio 4.1.1 :

1. Run Android Studio until the `Welcome to Android Studio` screen shows up.
2. Select `Get from Version Control`.
3. Paste the `URL`.
4. Press `Clone` button.

This will import the complete repository , but you won't be able to `run` the app yet (exactly as mentioned in your question) .

1. Now close and re open Android Studio
2. On `welcome screen`, select `import Project (Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc.)`
3. Navigate to the folder where the project was downloaded and select the required Sub-folder
4. Press OK and let the Studio build your project.