# Android. Firebase: Different applicationIdSuffix. Where save google-services.json?

Tags: android, firebase

I has project with 2 build types.
Every build type has specific **applicationIdSuffix**.

BuildType : **dev** , `applicationIdSuffix` = **.dev**

BuildType : **prod** , `applicationIdSuffix` = **.prod**

In Firebase console I create application for build type = **dev**.

As result I download file `google-services.json`. I put it in `c:\myproject\android\app\`

In this file `"package_name": "com.myproject.dev"`

OK.  It's work.

Now I in Firebase for the **same project,** I need to create another application with another buildType = **prod**.

As result I download **NEW** file: `google-services.json`.
In this file `"package_name": "com.myproject.prod"`

Where I need to put this second file **google-services.json**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firebase already supports that, you should create a new project, then add 2 new apps for each build type (mypackage.prod and mypackage.dev) or flavor.

Once done, just export the google-services.json of the last created app (dev), the file should contain details of both apps, like the following

```
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "...",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "mypackage.dev"
        }
      },

      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "...",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "mypackage.prod"
        }
```

Comment: This is the closest thing I could come up with in regards to a a source: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace the `google-services.json`  with existing one.Because Firebase automatically generates all the necessary attributes in `google-services.json` file having multiple build flavors in single project

Just remember every-time download new `google-services.json` and replace it after adding new flavor in your existing project