# Remove Gradle Warnings: Could not find google-services.json

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Switched from **`google-services:3.1.1 to 3.2.0`** since then I get the following warning

```
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]

Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
```

I see in my gradle console that the `JSON` file is parsed from the right place, as it is expected if you didn't use any flavors.

```
Parsing json file: C:\testApp\app\google-services.json
```

So building works fine.

But I really like a clean console output, so how can I remove this warning that seems not needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072568/how-to-add-google-services-json-in-android

Comment: I have checked the other question, and I see it not as duplication.
To make it clear building of the app and finding of google-service.json in the app folder works.

I only want to understand why this warning is be displayed and if it can be removed

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This appears to be fixed with **`com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2`** which was [released on July 13, 2018](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gms/google-services/4.0.2).

Gradle output with google-services:4.0.2:

```
> Configure project :app

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /.../build/app/google-services.json

> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /.../build/app/google-services.json
```

Gradle output with google-services:4.0.1:

```
> Configure project :app
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /.../build/app/google-services.json

> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /.../build/app/google-services.json
```

Comment: Updating to com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2 solves the problem for me, too

Answer (score 14):

It's a known regression. Check Google Issue [#110321069](https://issuetracker.google.com/110321069) for details. Until a fix is provided, it's safe to just ignore the warning.

Comment: This is realy a shame, but thanks for the info, so I would say this is now the answer.

Comment: I'm getting "Access Denied" for the linked issue. Has the issue been made private? Where can we follow for updates?

Comment: I've created a new public issue for this bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110321069. Please star the issue if this bug affects you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with the Google Services gradle plugin. I've created a public bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110321069

If you want to work around the issue and hide the warnings, you can copy your `google-service.json` into `app/src/debug` and `app/src/release`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

put google-services.json

under the path add

```
 1. [your project]\platforms\android\app\src\debug

 2. [your project]\platforms\android\app\src\release
```