# I can't compile a Github Code in Android Studio (sync failed with 5 errors)

Tags: android, android-studio, development-environment

I download this code [AnimeFlv](https://github.com/jordyamc/Animeflv) and import to android studio (last version) with the option Import Project (Gradle,  Eclipse ADT, etc.)

But the sync fail with 5 errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library.
Open File
Show Details
```

**And If I run give me this error.**

```
14:36:59: Executing task 'assemble'...

Executing tasks: [assemble]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :library.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :library: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
14:37:00: Task execution finished 'assemble'.
```

What its wrong? I am newbie with this, Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `google-services.json` then Refreshing gradle would help.

Since error cleary says :

> Could not find google-services.json while looking in

**Read this:** [How to add google-services.json in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072568/how-to-add-google-services-json-in-android)

---

But also, try to *copy & paste* the codes to a new generated project from GitHub source. As you might see, there would be more errors in future compilation except this.